# Will be nice to have "force flair cache update"

Tags: feature-request, flair, caching

I know there is a flair cache (about 24 hours to expire). I understand that this is needed for performance. It will be nice however to have ability to click "force flair update".

It can be CAPTCHA-protected, so people will not use it if they don't really need. This way it will not be a performance killer, right?

Sometimes folks just can't wait to see their new badge or some other "big accomplishment" on their flair.